# Can't get node to center in a StackPane with TornadoFX

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I am trying to make a simple view where I have a background node (*for now, I have a text node here but the final node will be a SVG path*) behind a `VBox`. I'm trying to get my background node to be centered within the root `StackPane` before I move on to implementing the `VBox`, but I can't seem to get my node centered properly.

Here are my classes:

```
class UserInputUI : App(InputView::class, UIStyles::class) {
  init {
    reloadStylesheetsOnFocus()
  }

  override fun start(stage: Stage) {
    stage.minWidth = 1024.0
    stage.minHeight = 768.0
    super.start(stage)
  }
}

class InputView : View() {
  override val root = StackPane()

  init {
    text("I wish to be centered") {
      stackpaneConstraints {
        alignment = Pos.CENTER
        addClass(UIStyles.headerFontStyle)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my `UIStyles` class.. if it's relevant.

```
class UIStyles : Stylesheet() {
  companion object {
    val headerFontStyle by cssclass()
    private val headerFontColor = Color.BLACK
  }

  init {
    headerFontStyle {
      fontSize = 48.px
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a different way I'm supposed to be centering the node in the middle of a `StackPane`? I've tried `root.alignment = Pos.CENTER` in the `InputView` init function also, but to no avail.

[image: help this poor box]

I feel like I'm doing something dumb.. any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `super.start()` call before the `minWidth/Height` set calls.

Comment: Huh! That seems to have done it. Not sure exactly why, but it's working now! Thank you!

Comment: Tip: Try using the builders to create your stackpane as well: `override val root = stackpane { text("...") }`. That way you don't need the init block, and the code looks a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

We have discussed this on Slack, and we believe there might be a JavaFX discrepancy between Linux and Mac/Windows, since your code works out of the box on Mac/Windows but fails on Linux.

When you place the `super.start()` call before the `minWidth/minHeight` configuration, the Scene will already have been created for you, so I believe that to be the cause.

A StackPane will by default center it's children, so there is no need for the `stackpaneConstraints` configuration. Your code would also look a lot cleaner if you use the builders to define the stackpane as well:

```
class InputView : View() {
    override val root = stackpane {
        text("I wish to be centered")
    }
}
```

Comment: yes its very curious that the original code does not work on linux but does on osx/win.. i'm using 4.470-1-MANJARO, if that helps! and thank you! now that I have placed the minwidth/height below the stage start i have been able to remove the stackpaneConstraints and everything is much cleaner now :-)

Comment: (also thank you so much for the work you do on tornadofx, it is absolutely wonderful and saved me from a nightmare of Swing ux development)

Comment: I had a thought: the issue might be because my linux distro automatically installed openjfx with openjdk instead of oracle's jdk/jfx, and there might be a compatibility issue there

Comment: Glad to hear it: About OpenJDK: That could be the issue, but I think one of the guys on Slack tried it with OracleJDK. Please report back if it's working for you with OracleJDK!